# Безопасно ли использовать триггеры в InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, проектирование, innodb

Допустим ставим триггер на покупку товара, триггер списывает средства со счета пользователя, это безопасно? Будет ли автоматически применена транзакция?

Comment: триггер работает в той же транзакции которая его породила. Если вы фиксируете транзакцию покупки, то и списание денег будет зафиксировано. А если откатываете покупку то и списание будет откачено. Триггера для того и придуманы

Comment: А если я не буду самостоятельно открывать транзакцию для покупки, разве innodb не сделает ее автоматически для пары покупка + списание средств (триггер)?

Comment: любая операция в innoDB работает в транзакции, даже если вы ее не начинали. Либо выполнится все, либо, при ошибке, будет откачено все. Это справедливо если все участвующие таблицы innoDB. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html  Читать со слов: "For transactional tables, failure of a statement should cause rollback of all changes performed by the statement"

Comment: то есть проблем быть не должно, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: Да, проблем быть не должно

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Ответ из комментариев от [Mike](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/194569/mike)*

Любая операция в InnoDB работает в транзакции, даже если вы ее не начинали. Либо выполнится все, либо, при ошибке, будет откачено все. Это справедливо если все участвующие таблицы InnoDB.

Триггер работает в той же транзакции которая его породила. Если вы фиксируете транзакцию покупки, то и списание денег будет зафиксировано, а если откатываете покупку то и списание будет откачено.